# Updatable Microsoft Access Combo box that doesn't insert into a table

Tags: ms-access-2010

I need a combo box that can be bound to a table and accept a new entry without inserting that new entry into the table until all of the other fields in the record is ready to be inserted.  I tried using code where you use a SQL Insert statement however when I want to save the rest of the data on the form to a table the rest of the data is showing up on a new record.  So I have one record with nothing but the project name and another record with everything else.
I have also tried this:

```
Append2Table = acDataErrContinue
    vField = cbo.ControlSource
    If Not (IsNull(vField) Or IsNull(NewData)) Then
        sMsg = "Do you wish to add the entry " & NewData & " for " & cbo.Name & "?"
        If MsgBox(sMsg, vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, "Add new value?") = vbOK Then
            Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(cbo.RowSource)
            rst.AddNew
                rst(vField) = NewData
            rst.Update
            rst.Close
            Append2Table = acDataErrAdded
        End If
    End If
```

I don't want to use edit because I will have a lot of records with the same project name and when I used the insert statement to add the project name I don't know anyway to have it return the ID field so that I could search for that and edit the record with the rest of the information.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Firstly, Access 2010 has a built in feature for adding records to a lookup table when they do not exist yet. That would save you writing all the above code.

Comment: I have the combo box where the Row source is a query and the Row Source Type is a table/Query.  I have to do this because there are so many projects to be display.  The built in feature for combo boxes only work when the Row Source Type is a Value List. I get the "The text you entered isn't an item in the list" when I try to type something new in.

Comment: Built in feature also works when `Row Source` is a table or query.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to add the lookup item only if it is going to be used, hence the waiting for the insert.

I don't see how this is possible, because you are going to need the ID of the lookup value in order to do the insert.

I don't recommend doing the insert by hand, it is messy, let Access do it for you.

I think the best idea in this case is to let the user enter the lookup item and have some cleanup mechanism when the form closes to remove any unused items from the lookup table.